# async await issue from express api to front end issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express

From express API after success return promise but in front-end with react how can I use this promise in dispatch payload in react state hook I want to directly push response data in the payload. Don't want to use then and catch.

**Backend**

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const authUser = await Employee.findById(req.decoded.userid).select('-password');
    console.log(authUser);
    return res.status(200).json({ success: true, authUser });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false, msg: 'Server error' });
  }
});
```

**Frontend**

```
const loadUser = async () => {
  try {
    const response = axios.get('/api/auth');
    //console.log(response)
    response
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADED,
      payload: response.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: AUTH_ERROR,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

```
//with Redux-thunk middleware.
const loadUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/auth');
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADED,
      payload: response.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: AUTH_ERROR,
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

as you already using async function cann't you do:

```
const loadUser = async ()=>{

    try {
        const response = await axios.get("/api/auth");
        console.log(response)
        dispatch({
            type:USER_LOADED,
            payload:response.data
        })
   } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        dispatch({
            type:AUTH_ERROR
        })
    }

}
```